# how to resolve a chord progression that goes f#m d#dim

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions

This is probably a stupid question but I've been trying to resolve it for a while now and due to low knowledge of music theory, I can't. I don't really know what key I'm in.

Comment: Is this homework? In the key of E major, F♯m is the ii chord with a predominant function, D♯dim is the vii° chord with a dominant function. (It is the upper 3 notes of a B7 chord, which is the V7.) So... in E major you would resolve to...?

Comment: another way to solve this problem is to try out chords until you find something that sounds good...*THEN* try to figure out what is going on.

Comment: There aren‘t any stupid questions, never!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is list out all the tones of the chords and then find a key signature they all belong to: `D# F# A C#`.

So follow the circle of fifths for sharp keys until you get a match...

```
1#: G/Em  - F#
2#: D/Bm  - F# C#
3#: A/F#m - F# C# G#
4#: E/C#m - F# C# G# D#
...
```

You should see that your set of notes matches `E` or `C#m`.

That's the 'mechanical' part of the issue, but now we get to the *actual* important part: there isn't a single answer to this question. Or, you might say it isn't answerable.

In `E` we could continue the harmony as `ii viio6 I` or `ii viio6 V7`.

In `C#m` we could continue the harmony as `iv iio6 i6` or `iv6 iio6/4 V7`.

There are other possibilities.

You probably expect the answer to simply be 'it resolves to `E` major, because that 'resolves' the diminished triad treating it as the leading tone triad `viio`. But it's really wrong to think that is *the one answer*.

Comment: Beware of restricting yourself to diatonic chords in one key.   II7 V7 I is as common as ii7 V7 I.

Comment: True. But, I only used the plain `ii` (`iv` in minor) because that was the chord in the question.

Answer (score 0):

A nice solution would be:

**Starting in A** :

A - f# - d#dim - A/E - E7 - A  -> I -vi - (vii°7) - I46 - V - I

d#dim would be a secondary vii°7 to A/E (I46) with the final E - A = V - I